# Magento 2 header custom block not cacheable for customer session

Tags: magento2, cache, customer-session

Magento 2 header custom block not `cache-able` for customer session for example

```
<referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
                 <block class="Company\Genaral\Block\Genaral" name="order.dropdown" before="minicart" template="Magento_Theme::html/custom.phtml" cacheable="false" />
</referenceContainer>
```

**I write code in phtml**

```
<?php $helperUrl = $this->helper('Company\Genaral\Helper\Data'); ?>
<?php $ckcustomer = $helperUrl->getcustomerSession(); ?>
 <?php if($ckcustomer !=1): ?>
   <li class="item link-login">
                <a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $helperUrl->getAccountLoginUrl() ?>">
                  <div>
                      <i class="rb-icon rb-icon-personal-information"></i>
                      <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Login'); ?></span>
                  </div>
                </a>
                </li>
<?php else: ?>
<li class="item link-logout"><a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $helperUrl->getLogoutUrl() ?>"><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Logout'); ?></a></li>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

**Anyone know why it's not working.**

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: yes i found solution.

Comment: Please post it as answer

Answer (score 2):

In Your Helper

```
    protected $isCustomerLoggedIn;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context $httpContext
    ) {
        $this->isCustomerLoggedIn = $httpContext->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH);
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_isScopePrivate = true;
    }

    public function getcustomerSession()
    {
        return $this->isCustomerLoggedIn;
    }
```

In Phtml

```
<?php $helperUrl = $this->helper('Company\Genaral\Helper\Data'); ?>
<?php $ckcustomer = $helperUrl->getcustomerSession(); ?>
<?php if ($ckcustomer == 1): ?> 

<?php endif; ?>
```